# How do i return a certain max number of items from a collection using linq

Tags: linq, collections

I have code below that builds a collection and returns it sorted by a property

```
var appChanges = GetHistory().ToList();
return appChanges.OrderByDescending(r => r.Change.When);
```

i want this to only return a max of 50 items (or total if collection size is less than 50)

how can i do this in LINQ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for **Take**.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx

```
appChanges.OrderByDescending(r => r.Change.When).Take(50);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `.Take(...)` function.

You can also use `.Skip(..)` in conjunction with it for paging queries.

Also, you'll want to avoid using `.ToList()` so early if you can avoid it because it will evaluate the query and return a result set.

Answer (score 2):

```
return appChanges.OrderByDescending(r => r.Change.When).Take(n);
```